# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when taking first occurence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the first occurence of unique values of **chain_id** in a pandas df. I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(columns="Sender", "Subject", "Body", "Datetime", "chain_id"


first_occurrence_df = df[re.match(pd.unique(chain_id), df.chain_id),]
```

But it is returning the error; unhashable type: numpy.ndarray. Yes, I know it is to do with the 'shape' of the df. But I am completely new to coding with no prior knowledge of it - so can anyone explain this in lay man's terms? And how do I get around this?

I have 3 other variables: "Sender", "Subject", "Body", "Datetime", "chain_id". All are strings with the exception of Datetime, being date format. chain_id identifies the email chain.

Error message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [232], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import re
----> 2 first = df[re.match(pd.unique(df.chain_id), df.chain_id),]

File C:\Anaconda3\envs\universal\lib\re.py:191, in match(pattern, string, flags)
    188 def match(pattern, string, flags=0):
    189     """Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    190     a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)

File C:\Anaconda3\envs\universal\lib\re.py:294, in _compile(pattern, flags)
    292     flags = flags.value
    293 try:
--> 294     return _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
    295 except KeyError:
    296     pass

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [mre]. There is no way we can tell you why the problem occurs on that line, because there are several things mentioned in that line that are defined elsewhere, and we have no way to *verify* that all of those things *are what they are supposed to be*. It's also a good idea to show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error messages - copied and pasted, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and formatted like code.

Comment: Finally: please do not tag your IDE unless you have a good reason to think the problem is caused by your IDE or somehow involves it. People who know a lot about using VS Code have no particular advantage in answering a question like this. However, since you are using a Pandas Dataframe, those *are* related concepts worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Karl, I've added the above.

Answer (score 1):

So, just to be clear, what you want is the first row where each `chain_id` occurs?  You can use

```
first = df.drop_duplicates( ['chain_id'], keep='first' )
```

Keeping the first is the default, but since it is important, you might as well specify it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The above does work for the purposes of what I am trying to achieve so thanks a lot on that front.